# How to display info for a row on clicking a button inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have been trying to show an information label for a row when clicking a button inside a UITableViewCell.
But I am unable to get the coordinates of the cell when the table is scrolled. 
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the coordinates?

Anyway, if you have the UIButton or UITableViewCell object, you can

```
[view convertPoint:CGPoint(0, 0) toView:nil];
```

to get the absolute coordinates in the window.